# SSRS 2016 showing some blank data on report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

I have a weird problem. I am upgrading my SQL Server Reporting Services from 2008 to 2016. New reports uploaded to 2016 work fine.

I'm using SQL Server Data Tool 2015 to migrate my old 2008 reports to 2016.

The early 2008 reports are running fine in SSDT. As soon as they are on the report server, some columns are not displaying data on screen but printing it or exporting to PDF is fine.. none of the columns have hidden properties set. There is no pattern to this behavior..  has anyone come across this issue?

I don't want to have to rewrite all these reports again!

Comment: What version of reportviewer are you using?

Comment: @MasterYoda - I use SSDT 2015 , a cut down version of VS really.. I've also tried it in VS 2015.. still the same with Report Builder 2016. Mind you.. this is for building the report.. I use either IE 11 or Edge to render the report and they both have the same problem. I'm not delivering the reports through any other app.. just straight reporting